# Save results to csv file without open csv with Python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have function and a dataframe as show below:

```
def rand_million()
    df = some calculating
    return df   

df =
       index           boolvalue  
2014-05-21 10:00:00          9.9        
2014-05-21 11:00:00         10.3        
2014-05-21 12:00:00          4.3   
2014-05-21 13:00:00          3.7        
2014-05-21 14:00:00          5.4        
2014-05-21 15:00:00            0 
...

and len(df) = 1000
```

this dataframe is calculated by a function call 'rand_million' and the results would be different everytime, I would like to calculate the function 1 million times and store them to csv.

I expect to receive just one csv (for example named 'simulationresult') as show below

```
1 time        9.9, 10.3, 4.3, 3.7, 5.4, 0, ...    <- 1000 results
2 time        .....                               <- 1000 results

.....

1000000 time  ....                                <- 1000 results
```

I think the framework would look like this:

```
for i in range(0,10000):
    df = rand_million()
    store df to simulationresult line(i+1)
    clear df    <- "in oder to save memory"
    ...something like this
```

However I couldn't find a better way to handle it. I saw someone tried to calculate all the results and then stored it in one time, but in this case it seems not a good idea. Does anyone have a better idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. What's wrong with simply calling [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) on the final product?

Comment: If you don't want to store into csv file, you can dump your df using pickle and load it when you need it. So you load a variable. But this won't be very different from saving a csv...

Comment: @Alan I tried to use  to_csv but It seems the data couldn't be trasposed and store in the end as a matrix as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want this should get you going:

```
for i in range(1,10001):
    df = rand_million()
    df.to_csv('No_{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Comment: Maybe this answer will shed light on the issue :)

Comment: @alexis Sorry for misunderstanding, I have corrected the post

Comment: @Alan Sorry for misunderstanding, I have corrected the post

Answer (score 0):

Just write each row to csv and then call `fp.flush()`, where `fp` is the open filehandle you are writing to. Flushing writes out the line immediately, so your data is safe if your process dies before it completes all the passes.